# Fixed height scrollable div inside of a bootstrap 3 column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen similar questions, but nothing exactly like I'm trying. Most of the examples make the entire col-md-2 scroll, I need content within that to scroll.

Inside a fluid container, I have a left navigation type column, and a right content column.

Inside the left column I want a div at the top class="top", and a div at the bottom class="bottom". And in the middle I have a list. Say bottom and top are 100px. I want the list to take up all of the space between the two, and if the list content is larger than this area, I want it to scroll. If the list content is smaller than the space between the two, I want it to take up all of that space (not collapse).

Here is a psuedo example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2">

            <div class="top">
                . . .
            </div>

            <div class="scroll-area">
                <ul>
                    <li>one</li>
                    . . .
                    <li>one-thousand</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom">
                . . .
            </div>

         </div> 
         <div class="col-md-10 content">
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <style>
   .top, .bottom { height: 100px; }
  </style>
```

I was able to do this before without bootstrap by giving "scroll-area" absolute positioning.  I can make the scroll-area work with fixed positioning, but the containing "col-md-2 is collapsed, so "bottom" sits up top.

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: What is the width of left part and do you want to use Flexbox?

Comment: The width should fill 100% of the containing bootstrap column, which is col-md-2 right now col-md-2 is width: 16.66666667%;. So if I changed it to col-md-3 (width: 25%), the content should fill that.  I think flexbox would be ok.

Comment: Does left part have `position: fixed;`

Comment: negative. I talk about trying that in "scroll-area" in my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is for when you dont know the window height.

You can still achieve this using position:absolute;
you just tell the blue and red parts to take top and bottom,
the green part should have top 100px, and then you just use css 'calc' to get its height.

**Styles**

```
.side{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
}

.scroll-area{
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-top:100px;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 side">
          <div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;">
            <div class="top" style="background-color:red;top:0;width:100%;height: 100px; position:absolute;">
                top
            </div>

            <div class="scroll-area">
                <ul>
                    <li>one</li>
                </ul>
                <div style="width:100%;height:10000px;">
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>one-thousand</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom" style="background-color:blue;bottom:0;width:100%;height: 100px; position:absolute;">
                bottom
            </div>
          </div>

       </div> 
       <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-offset-2 content col-md-offset-2">
         <div style="height:1000px;width:100%;">

         </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

take a look at this filddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/jxo6pmju/12/

Comment: could you explain why you're using relative and fixed?

Comment: I wanted the sidecolumn to ignore the row height and have 100% height of the screen. Then i have used the relative inside so i can use absolute elemts inside of it. Is this not working for you?

Comment: The content pane is collapsing all the way left. I am using container-fluid, I added that to the question. But I added that to your example and it worked. Still trying to work it into my solution.

Comment: That problem is with the "row "div if you dont want fixed/absoulete items you will have to set its height too 100%. But the will restrict your page. It will be wrong... Can you add a fiddle of what you got so far?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Seems like you did it right, the only thing that you need, is because this the jsfiddle screen is small in width, you should use col-sm-2 so the side div will get the right width. But becuase its fixed, the div with the content floats to the left and i gnores it. So you will need to add to the main content div, the class col-sm-offset-2. This way it will space 2 columns to its left and will complete the 12 column grid. fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/Lsx1mfku/3/

Answer (score 2):

Here I added fiddle link for what you had problem, with .
Hope this helps`

```
<div class="fixed">
  <b>Fixed Content</b>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <p>top</p>
</div>
<div class="scrollit">
  <b>Scroll Content</b>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>


</div>
<div class="fixed">
  <b>Fixed Content</b>
  <br/>
  <br/> bottom
</div>
```

[scrollable middle section](https://jsfiddle.net/wy2g02n6/2/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, while your answer is ok as is, it would help OP more if you put an explanation of what you changed to make it work.

Comment: hi, the middle section can't be a static height.